# How do you run two statement at the same time?

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter, tk-toolkit, python-3.9

I have been making a game that requires me to execute two statements at the same time
I have tried to do it but at this point, I don't know how to do it
this is my code so far:

```
from tetris_loader import tetris_loader as loader
import time

loader()

while True:
    while signal == False:
        time.sleep(1)
    loader.window.destroy()
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Execute two statements at the same time'?

Comment: What statements are you trying to execute at the same time? Also don't think that while true is necessary.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? By adding function.
Snippet:

```
from tetris_loader import tetris_loader as loader
import time

loader()

def run():
    while True:
        while signal == False:
            time.sleep(1)
        loader.window.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```